# JQuery FadeIn effect and Omega Theme

Tags: theming, javascript

I am trying to use the fade in effect in Drupal when I load a page.

In my Omega sub-theme I have included the following line in its .info file.

```
scripts[] = '/js/custom.js'
```

In the script, I have included the following code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("body").css("display", "none");
$("body").fadeIn(2000);

});
```

If I load the page, I see no effect at all, but I clearly see that my JavaScript is in the header.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/innodru/sites/all/themes/CHILDTHEME/js/custom.js?m2zpiw"></script>
```

I have cleaned the cache and tried a lot of things, but it does not look like is working.
I am using Drupal 7.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using document.ready. Instead you should use drupal behaviors. Even though document.ready will work. Behaviors is the drupal 7 way to do things as these behaviors get called after ajax calls too.

**css**

```
body {display:none;}
```

**javascript**

```
(function ($) {
    Drupal.behaviors.fadein = {
            attach:function(context, settings){
                    $('body', $context).once().fadeIn(2000);
            }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

**And FYI**
Omega adds a 'responsivelayout' event that will get fired every time the layout is set/changed including when the page loads so you could potentially make the page display straight away on mobiles and fade in on others.

```
(function ($) {
    Drupal.behaviors.fadein = {
            attach:function(context, settings){
                $('body', context).bind('responsivelayout', function(e) {
                    if($('body', context).hasClass('responsive-layout-mobile')){
                            $('body').once().show();
                    }else{
                            $('body').once().fadeIn(2000);
                    }
                });
            }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

I have not tested the code BTW, but you get the idea

Comment: +1 for using Drupal.behaviors. I would recommend to change `body {display:none;}` to `.js body {display:none;}`. The 'js' class is automatically added to the html element if javascript is enabled. This way the body remains visible for visitors who have javascript disabled.

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7 you need to wrap your jQuery in another function to use the $ alias.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681309/using-jquery-in-drupal-7

```
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").css("display", "none");
    $("body").fadeIn(2000);
  });
})(jQuery);
```

But trying to fade in the entire body of a page sounds dubious, especially with the Omega theme which contains a lot of special JS and CSS to handle automatic re-sizing... I don't know how friendly your fade in will play with the resizer stuff from Omega.

Comment: Also, if the page needs a bit longer to load, the user will see the content while loading. Only after complete load the body disappears and fades in again. Questionable.

Further, instead of $(document) you can also use jQuery(document) in Drupal 7.

Comment: Hi actually I tried to use the script but nothing happens. The site will be an internal site for some touch screen, so size is not an issue (everything will be local) and I am trying to add some eyecandy. The Body was a test mostly, I will use some blocks instead. But really nothing moves.

Comment: Have you used [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or Chrome's Developer console to check for Javascript errors?

Comment: My advice would be to wrap the code in Drupal.behaviour http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941426/drupal-behaviours

Answer (score 0):

I set the css to

```
body {
   display:none;
}
```

and then display it with a script

```
 (function($) {     
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('body').fadeIn();
    });

    })(jQuery);
```